# How To Show Different Footers For Different Post Types Pages?

Tags: themes, customization

I know I can add some codes using:- is_front_page

But, I want to add different codes into footer of different post types. Then what can I use instead of is_front_page

Answer (score 1):

You can use `is_singular()` instead.

According to [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_singular), you can use this function the following way:

`is_singular($post_type);`

Then you can print your desired code into footer the following way:

```
function my_footer_code() {
    if ( is_singular('my-post-type') ){
        //Your code here
    }
}
add_action('wp_footer','my_footer_code');
```

Comment: It's not working in my case. Please visit my site http://grabsale.in You can see I have added a line "It will show only on homepage" above my footer in homepage. I want to add different texts (store descriptions) in different store pages. Please tell me how can I do it?

Comment: @ShibamKar I can't see the line you mentioned. Are you sure you are using the right post type? And where are you using this code? I tested the code before posting the answer.

Comment: I am using it on footer.php